# Sending SMS inside my App

Tags: ios, ios7, sms, imessage

I use MFMessageComposeViewController to send SMS inside my App. Is there a way to know if the message was sent using iMessage or regular cellular services?

Answer (score 1):

No. You do not even know if it was sent out at all. I wish there was such feature in iOS SDK.

Comment: Like @Teddy said, you don't get any information about the status of messages sent with Message Compose View. You don't know if it failed, sent, when it sent or anything. Once you start the compose view you are dealing with the OS not the app.